# How to include page number in endnotes made with enotez

Tags: page-numbering, endnotes, enotez

I'm using `enotez` with the `octavo` class and want to include in each endnote the page number to which it refers, but so far all I can do is include the page number on which the endnote actually appears. I've tried all kinds of complicated stuff none of which works, so for an MWE I'll just use the simplest version I've used (which also doesn't work).

```
\documentclass[openany]{octavo}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \thepage.}.
\clearpage
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \thepage.}.
\clearpage
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \thepage.}.
\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a possibility for you, `postnotes` has some infrastructure to store some context information from the mark and make it available at the printed note. `\thepage` is made available as `\pnthepage` and you can thus use it directly.

```tex
\documentclass[openany]{octavo}
\usepackage{postnotes}
\begin{document}
Some text\postnote{This is an end note to page \pnthepage.}
\clearpage
Some text\postnote{This is an end note to page \pnthepage.}
\clearpage
Some text\postnote{This is an end note to page \pnthepage.}
\clearpage
\printpostnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `enotez` you can also get it to work, but you have to handle the cross-reference yourself:

```tex
\documentclass[openany]{octavo}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \pageref{en:1}.}\label{en:1}.
\clearpage
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \pageref{en:2}.}\label{en:2}.
\clearpage
Some text\endnote{This is an end note to page \pageref{en:3}.}\label{en:3}.
\clearpage
\printendnotes
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's got to be enotez, unfortunately, but dealing with the cross-reference is something I can handle.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Nothing unfortunate about that, it's a good package.